# Coordinate-free derivation of the Einstein's field equation from the Hilbert action.

Tags: general-relativity, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

It is well-known that the equation for stationary solutions of the Einstein-Hilbert functional (without matter and cosmological constant, which is irrelevant here):
$$S = \int_M R \mu_g,$$
is given by the Einstein's field equation:
$$Ric -\frac{1}{2}R g = 0, $$
where $\mu_g$ is the canonical volume form given by the metric $g$, $Ric$ is the Ricci curvature and $R$ is the Ricci scalar.

The standard derivation of the above statement seems to be a not so hard but not so pleasant direct calculation, either in coordinates or abstract indices, expanding everything in terms of the Christoffel symbol and eventually in terms of $g$ and then calculus.

My questions is: is there a more geometric and coordinate-free way to derive this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be found in Besse "Einstein Manifolds", in chapter 4.

The idea is to use Koszul formula for the Levi-Civitta connection to compute the derivative of the curvature with respect to the metric. Bianchi identities also help.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is indeed a coordinate-free calculation. Still, it is just the standard derivation in the coordinate-free notation. So I didn't formulate my problem well as I was hoping for something more geometrical rather than algebra, say in terms of parallel transport or something of that kind. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Thomas Richard 

Is there some free resource in internet on this argument?